# Cakephp find on related models

Tags: cakephp

I have an issue with cakephp find method when apply a condition on a related model. Here is my scenario

`Machine belongsTo Category`
`Machine hasAndBelongsToMany Products` (products produced by machines)

Now I want all those categories with machines that hasandbelongs to a particular product.

i.e the result set should be like the following array!

```
Category 1 
   Machine 1 (that can produce for example product1)
   machine 2 (that can produce product 1)
Category 2
  machine 3 (that can produce product 1)
  machine 4 (that can produce product 1)
```

I have tried the containable behavior and joins but no luck.

Comment: let's see some code that you have tried for us to build off of. You should have something like this : `$this->Machine->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('Product.name'=>'Some product name')));`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cakephp, Retreive Data for HABTM Models using conditional find](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488524/cakephp-retreive-data-for-habtm-models-using-conditional-find)